# Remote report processing requires Microsoft SQL Server 2008 reporting Services or later

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I have already create  a SQL server 2005 report and host it successfully in sql server 2008 server .The report can be viewed in the browser .Now I want to integrate  the report in a WPF application.And I used the report viewer control to display the report. I am using .net 4.0 framework and VS 2010.Below is the code for rendering the report.Below is the code that successfully rendering the report in the page when  I am using sql server 2008 R2 edition.

```
             try
             {
                repViewer.ProcessingMode =     Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;

                repViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://tfs    /ReportServer$Sql2005");
                repViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Suman Reports/Report1";
                repViewer.RefreshReport();
             }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                throw ex;
              }
```

give me the message "Remote report processing requires Microsoft  SQL Server 2008 reporting Services or later".Is there any option to use it in the wpf application with out changing to sql server 2008.I am new in the field of SSRS & integration .Please guide me on thise.